# Resizable dynamic d3.js graphs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I would like to be able to do the following.

1: A html page is loaded with 9 d3 graphs 65px x 65px big.

2: User clicks any one of the graphs.

3: The graphs is expanded as some nice popup not having to reload anything.

4: The new popup has scrollable x axis so i can scale up and down.

So my questions are.

Is this possible?

What would be the required technology?

Any of you have done something simmular and have code to share?

Is there a better alternativ then d3 to do this? It must be free for internal company use.

Comment: All of this is possible. Would you mind sharing the code you have?

Comment: I have no code since i have no experince with d3 that is why i would like to know what technology i should google.